# Python - String.split() using delimiter ',', but there is price in string also using comma in thousand

Tags: python, csv, parsing, delimiter

I am trying to use Python to parse a CSV file. I have a string like this:

> "11/11/14","Buy","1,900","$10.40","-$19,760.00"

I want to parse it to into list like this

- element 1 -> "11/11/14"
- element 2 -> "Buy"
- element 3 -> "1,900"
- element 4 -> "$10.40"
- element 5 -> "-$19,760.00"

However, since there is comma delimiter in thousands number, the parse result is

- element 1 -> "11/11/14"
- element 2 -> "Buy"
- element 3 -> "1
- element 4 -> 900"
- element 5 -> "$10.40"
- element 6 -> "-$19
- element 7 -> 760.00"

Here is my code:

```
data = line.split(',')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to look at the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) in the python standard library. This will automatically take care of quoted strings within the elements of the CSV. For example:

```
with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='\"')
    for row in spamreader:
        print(', '.join(row))
```

This will load in a file and read it line by line, then print out the contents of each element separated by a comma. The result should match what you need.

Comment: I use with open('eggs.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
'r' insdead of 'rb'
using 'rb' gives me an error like this

_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Comment: I think it depends on the version of python you are using (2 or 3). The code snippet above is taken directly from the linked documentation for Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

use,

```
data = line.strip('"').split('","')
```

There's no `"Quote"` in prices.

Comment: The problem I see with this is that you don't lose the first and last double quote in the string. As such the first and last entries in the list end up being `'"11/11/14'` and `'-$19,760.00"'` respectively.

Comment: Oh, yes. If it was simple string, then it would have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Split on `"\",\""` instead, then assuming there are no spaces in your delimiter it'll work, otherwise use regex to allow spaces.

Comment: That won't work. `""\"` alone isn't a valid Python string. And `str.split()` takes a string, not a regular expression in Python

Comment: Sure split doesn't take a regular expression, but that's no reason you can't find a module that will split on a regex.

Comment: Right, the `re` module specifically, but might as well just go for the `csv` module, as answered

Comment: Besides, you've not accounted for the beginning an ending `"` characters on the line that are not between any elements.

Comment: True, I figured that was self explanatory though, I like to give the programmers here a little credit for being able to clean up the edge cases. But yeah the `csv` module seems like the way to go.